# Análise sintática da oração "que se tornara extremamente rico"

Tags: português-brasileiro, sintaxe

Olá!

A análise sintática que fiz da oração "que se tornara extremamente rico" está correta?

---

Era uma vez, em um país muito distante, um mercador tão venturoso em suas atividades, ***que se tornara extremamente rico***.

---

**Oração Subordinada Adverbial Consecutiva**

**Sujeito simples**: que

**Predicado nominal**: se tornou extremamente rico.

**Verbo de ligação**: se tornou

**Predicativo do Sujeito**: extremamente rico

**Adjunto adverbial**: extremamente (em relação ao adjetivo "rico")